# What are these seedlings?

Tags: identification, weeds, seedlings

Click for large image:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I planted a spider-plant cutting, in a pot that included some home-made compost.
The pot has sprouted 4 tiny seedlings.
Can anyone identify them from these pictures?

- If I gently squeeze the leaves, then it has a very strong (bitter?) vegetal smell, somewhat reminiscent of ivy.
- The compost in question is about evenly kitchen waste (so fair amounts of veg seeds/fruit pips) and shredded garden waste (so lots of shredded weeds), so I assume it's one of those.
- The pot plant isn't terribly close to sunlight, so the seedlings are likely to be unusually etiolated.

[Last time I had an unexpected seedling in with something else, it turned out to be a sunflower](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/34250/any-guesses-what-these-seedlings-are-and-whether-i-should-remove-them), so I'm relunctant to *just* throw it away. :)

Any guesses what these are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Cotyledons (first leaves) of some kind of squash.  I recently planted some pumpkin seeds from a leftover Halloween pumpkin just to try it and the leaves look real similar.
[image: Pumpkin Seedlings]

Comment: That's extremely likely the garden compost added to the pot regularly has squash innards added to it.